# How to combine 3 or more CompletionStages?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8

If have 2 CompletionStages, I can combine them with `thenCombine` method:

```java
CompletionStage<A> aCompletionStage = getA();
CompletionStage<B> bCompletionStage = getB();
CompletionStage<Combined> combinedCompletionStage =
    aCompletionStage.thenCombine(bCompletionStage, (aData, bData) -> combine(aData, bData));
```

If I have 3 or more CompletionStages, I can make a chain of `thenCombine` methods, but I have to use temporary objects to pass results. For example, here is a solution using `Pair` and `Triple` from the `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple` package:

```java
CompletionStage<A> aCompletionStage = getA();
CompletionStage<B> bCompletionStage = getB();
CompletionStage<C> cCompletionStage = getC();
CompletionStage<D> dCompletionStage = getD();

CompletionStage<Combined> combinedDataCompletionStage =
        aCompletionStage.thenCombine(bCompletionStage, (Pair::of))
                .thenCombine(cCompletionStage, (ab, c) ->
                        Triple.of(ab.getLeft(), ab.getRight(), c))
                .thenCombine(dCompletionStage, (abc, d) ->
                        combine(abc.getLeft(), abc.getMiddle(), abc.getRight(), d));
```

Is there a better way to combine results from multiple CompletionStages?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is your `combine` method? What's its purpose? What do you want to do with the `CompletionStage`s? Who is the consumer at the end? What should be the result they receive?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, `combine` is a function taking 4 parameters and returning 1 of type `Combined`. The consumer can be for example another function taking `Combined` as a parameter and returning another `CompletionStage`, which is invoked using `combinedDataCompletionStage.thenCompose(...)`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The only way to combine multiple stages that scales well with a growing number of stages, is to use `CompletableFuture`. If your `CompletionStage`s aren’t `CompletableFuture`s you may still convert them using `.toCompletableFuture()`:

```
CompletableFuture<A> aCompletionStage = getA().toCompletableFuture();
CompletableFuture<B> bCompletionStage = getB().toCompletableFuture();
CompletableFuture<C> cCompletionStage = getC().toCompletableFuture();
CompletableFuture<D> dCompletionStage = getD().toCompletableFuture();

CompletionStage<Combined> combinedDataCompletionStage = CompletableFuture.allOf(
    aCompletionStage, bCompletionStage, cCompletionStage, dCompletionStage)
    .thenApply(ignoredVoid -> combine(
        aCompletionStage.join(), bCompletionStage.join(),
        cCompletionStage.join(), dCompletionStage.join()) );
```

This contains more boilerplate than combining two stages via `thenCombine` but the boilerplate doesn’t grow when adding more stages to it.

---

Note that even with your original `thenCombine` approach, you don’t need a `Triple`, a `Pair` is sufficient:

```
CompletionStage<Combined> combinedDataCompletionStage =
    aCompletionStage.thenCombine(bCompletionStage, (Pair::of)).thenCombine(
        cCompletionStage.thenCombine(dCompletionStage, Pair::of),
        (ab, cd) -> combine(ab.getLeft(), ab.getRight(), cd.getLeft(), cd.getRight()));
```

Still, it doesn’t scale well if you want to combine more stages.

---

An in-between solution (regarding complexity) might be:

```
CompletionStage<Combined> combinedDataCompletionStage = aCompletionStage.thenCompose(
    a -> bCompletionStage.thenCompose(b -> cCompletionStage.thenCompose(
        c -> dCompletionStage.thenApply(d -> combine(a, b, c, d)))));
```

That’s simpler in its structure but still doesn’t scale well with more more stages.

Answer (score 10):

[Holger's third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005471/545298) can be made a little bit shorter:

```
CompletionStage<Combined> combinedDataCompletionStage = aCompletionStage.thenCompose(
    a -> bCompletionStage.thenCompose(
        b -> cCompletionStage.thenCombine(dCompletionStage,
            (c, d) -> combine(a, b, c, d))));
```

Answer (score 6):

Any number of CompletableFuture can be combined (reduced)

```
CompletionStage<A> futA = getA();
CompletionStage<B> futB = getB(); 
CompletionStage<C> futC = getC(); 

Stream.of(futA, futB, futC) 
    .reduce((f1, f2) -> f1.thenCombine(f2, (d1, d2) -> combine(d1, d2));
```

The implementation of *combine* method will be responsible to merge data values (A, B and C), which could be tricky if A, B and C are disparate.

Answer (score 5):

You asked about "3 or more", if you have them in a List as CompletableFutures (see other answers) you could use this handy method:

```
private static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> join(List<CompletableFuture<T>> executionPromises) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> joinedPromise = CompletableFuture.allOf(executionPromises.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new));
    return joinedPromise.thenApply(voit -> executionPromises.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

It converts your "list of futures" to a "future for a list of the results".

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use an intermediary object, but one of your own instead of using `Pair` and `Tuple`

```
public R method() {
    CompletableFuture<A> aFuture = getAFuture();
    CompletableFuture<B> bFuture = getBFuture();
    CompletableFuture<C> cFuture = getCFuture();
    CompletableFuture<D> dFuture = getDFuture();

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new WellNamedResultHolder())
            .thenCombineAsync(aFuture, WellNamedResultHolder::withAResult)
            .thenCombineAsync(bFuture, WellNamedResultHolder::withBResult)
            .thenCombineAsync(cFuture, WellNamedResultHolder::withCResult)
            .thenCombineAsync(dFuture, WellNamedResultHolder::withDResult)
            .thenApplyAsync(this::combineAllTheResults);
}

private static class WellNamedResultHolder {
    private A aResult;
    private B bResult;
    private C cResult;
    private D dResult;

    // Getters

    public WellNamedResultHolder withAResult(final A aResult) {
        this.aResult = aResult;
        return this;
    }

    public WellNamedResultHolder withBResult(final B bResult) {
        this.bResult = bResult;
        return this;
    }

    public WellNamedResultHolder withCResult(final C cResult) {
        this.cResult = cResult;
        return this;
    }

    public WellNamedResultHolder withDResult(final D dResult) {
        this.dResult = dResult;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The actual form of the result holder can obviously change to match your own needs, giving you greater flexibility. You also get to be in charge of what happens as these futures complete. Although there is more boilerplate, you get code that is more descriptive of what is happening (which lombok can tidy up).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but had more than 3 completablefutures so building up on [Holger's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004802/how-to-combine-3-or-more-completionstages/34005471#34005471) answer I made a small generic utility.

```
public static <T, R> CompletableFuture<R> allOf(List<CompletableFuture<T>> args, Function<List<T>, R> combiner) {
    final Queue<CompletableFuture<T>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    for (CompletableFuture<T> arg : args) {
        queue.add(arg);
    }
    return aggregator(queue, new ArrayList<>(), combiner);
}

private static <T, R> CompletableFuture<R> aggregator(Queue<CompletableFuture<T>> queue, List<T> arg,
        Function<List<T>, R> combiner) {
    if (queue.size() == 2)
        return queue.poll().thenCombine(queue.poll(), (c, d) -> {
            arg.add(c);
            arg.add(d);
            return combiner.apply(arg);
        });
    return queue.poll().thenCompose(data -> {
        arg.add(data);
        return aggregator(queue, arg, combiner);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that CompleableFuture.allOf() function can help you.

For example: (View full Class [here](https://gist.github.com/huantt/49f26c56699362755bee78a0090928d1))

```
    List<String> urls = [
            "https://webhook.site/1647465b-c28f-4ffe-bbfe-5d3ad95ef994",
            "https://webhook.site/1647465b-c28f-4ffe-bbfe-5d3ad95ef994?a=1"
    ]
    CompletableFuture<Response>[] futures = new Completablefuture[2]
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
        futures[i] = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(urls[i]).execute().toCompletableFuture()

    }

    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).thenApply { future ->
        return futures.collect { it.join() }
    }.thenApply({ responses ->
        //Do something with results
        responses.each { println("Status code: " + it.statusCode) }
    })
```

Comment: That's not Java syntax dude

Comment: i think that may be groovy ye

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function...

```java
combine3(
    futureA, futureB, futureC,
    (a, b, c) -> {
      // let's go!
    }).toCompletableFuture();
```

Definition:

```java
private static <A, B, C, D> CompletionStage<D> combine3(
        CompletionStage<A> aStage,
        CompletionStage<B> bStage,
        CompletionStage<C> cStage,
        TriFunction<A, B, C, D> f
) {
    return aStage.thenCompose(
            a -> bStage.thenCombine(cStage,
                    (b, c) -> f.apply(a, b, c)));
}

interface TriFunction<A, B, C, D> {
    D apply(A a, B b, C c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem (and likewise for `Optional`) so I wrote a library to generate `thenCombine`-methods up to arity 26: https://github.com/wernerdegroot/applicatives

Perhaps it will be of help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine results from multiple CFs you need an aggregator for that.

Take a look on the following example, on how to combine multiple CFs returning strings:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        var executor = CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        var cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "1", executor);
        var cf2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "2", executor);
        var cf3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "3", executor);
        var cf4 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "4", executor);

        var collectees = List.of(cf1, cf2, cf3, cf4);


        System.out.println(Instant.now() + ": before combine");
        var combinedFuture = combine(collectees);
        System.out.println(Instant.now() + ": after combine");
        // .get() is a blocking function
        // if you remove .get() the program will print uncompleted future and exit (e.g. works async)
        var result = combinedFuture.thenApply(list -> String.join(" - ", list)).get();
        System.out.println(Instant.now() + ": " + result);
    }

    static <T> CompletableFuture<? extends List<T>> combine(List<CompletableFuture<T>> input) {
        var collector = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new ArrayList<T>(input.size()));
        for (var toCollect : input) {
            collector = collector.thenCombine(toCollect, (ts, t) -> {
                ts.add(t);
                return ts;
            });
        }
        return collector;
    }
```

Comment: The original question asked about combining CompletionStages parametrized by different types.