# How to combine an asynchronous CompletableFuture with the completed CompletableFuture?

Tags: concurrency, java-8, future, completable-future

I looked into the following code:
[How to combine 3 or more CompletionStages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004802/how-to-combine-3-or-more-completionstages), but in this post only Completed task from CompletableFutures are combined.

How can i combine an asynchronous CompletableFuture with Completed CompletableFuture, so as to combine the results from an already completed completableFuture with the one whose result is yet to be calculated?

Comment: None of the code in the linked question depends on whether the futures are completed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` to convert any normal data to a `CompletableFuture` object and then use `thenCompose` from `CompletableFuture` to combine results from the Async operation. Sample code:

```
long userId = 12345678899L;
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(userId)
.thenCompose(userId -> getUserDeatils(userId))
.thenAccept(user -> doSomething(user));
// or thenApply(user -> doSomething(user))
```

where getUserDeatils(userId) could be like:

```
CompletableFuture<User> getUserDeatils(long userId) {
  // some async code to load user details
}
```