# How to access multiple Completablefuture Stage variables at the end

Tags: java, lambda, completable-future

Im trying to use multiple different variables at the end of a completablefuture pipe. Its hard to explain. Here is my example:

```
private void test(){
lib.getHumanFromDatabase().thenApplyAsync(human->{
        //returns one human from the database
        return human;
    }, executor).thenComposeAsync(humanFromDb-> {
        //Set new name of human
        humanFromDb.setName("NameOfHuman");
        //update human and return the new entity
        return lib.updateHumanInDatbase(humanFromDb);
    }, executor).thenComposeAsync(humanFromDb-> {
        //Then ask for his home
        return lib.getHomeOfHuman(humanFromDb);
    }).thenAcceptAsync(homeOfHuman-> {
        //So here at the end i want to access 
        //the variable humanFromDb AND
        //the variable homeOfHuman BUT
        //i only get homeOfHuman ...
    }, executor).handleAsync((ok, ex) -> {
        //Just for exception and so on
    }, executor);
}
```

I first tried to store the variables outside of lambda inside the method but here i get the information, that the variable has to be final. Is there any possebility to access both variables and the end to return them for example in some UI-Window or something? Maybe it is important, that both variables are of a different type.

Maybe it is not possible and i have to use a different approach? I have no clue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define all dependent stages with a single method chain, when there is just a single chain of dependencies. Otherwise, you have to store one or more stages in a variable, i.e.

```
private void test() {    
    CompletableFuture<Human> humanFuture =
        lib.getHumanFromDatabase().thenApplyAsync(human -> {
            //returns one human from the database
            return human;
        }, executor).thenComposeAsync(humanFromDb -> {
            //Set new name of human
            humanFromDb.setName("NameOfHuman");
            //update human and return the new entity
            return lib.updateHumanInDatbase(humanFromDb);
        }, executor);

    humanFuture.thenComposeAsync(humanFromDb -> {
          //Then ask for his home
          return lib.getHomeOfHuman(humanFromDb);
      }).thenAcceptBothAsync(humanFuture, (humanFromDb, homeOfHuman) -> {
          //So here you can now access humanFromDb, homeOfHuman

      }, executor).handleAsync((ok, ex) -> {
          //Just for exception and so on

      }, executor);
}
```

So here, you just need to remember the `humanFuture`, to pass it later on to `thenAcceptBothAsync` to create a stage depending on both, the `humanFuture` and the future which provides the `homeOfHuman` (which also depends on `humanFuture`).

Comment: Ok thanks ... i thought there would be a cleaner way to do this ... and what is if i need 4 variables at the end and not only 2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005471/2711488 I think, we need syntactical support for arbitrary functions first (true function types and/or tuples), before we can get a simple API for such tasks.

Comment: I face the same issue in existing project. Wish there was a cleaner way to do it like synchronised code. Due to above situation, code has become a nested hell of thenApply/thenAccept. Most of the time the multiple objects obtained in the initial chaining are required in the middle of the chain or at the end. There doesn't seem to be a cleaner solution to avoid nesting or combining. For combining independent tasks I agree that we have the apis like combine but for sequential tasks it is not a good solution.

Comment: @MohammedSalmanShaikh unless there’s a reason for changing the thread, you still can express a sequential chain of actions as a single block. There is no need to encapsulate every method call into a `then[Apply|Accept]` call.