# How can we compose 3 or more completablefutures while maintaining all the results

Tags: java, completable-future

I have 3 services which I want to chain

```
CompletableFuture<String> serviceA
CompletableFuture<String> serviceB(String resultFromA)
CompletableFuture<String> serviceC(String resultFromA, String resultFromB)
```

If I use thenCompose, I can't seem to maintain the first result

i.e.

```
serviceA.thenCompose(a -> serviceB(a))
        .thenCompose(b -> serviceC(a, b));  // a is lost
```

If I use CompletableFuture.allOf(), I don't see that it allows chaining - running in sequence and passing results.

I am going to modify serviceB, so that it returns a Pair, or some composite object, but is there a better way ?

Comment: See [How to access multiple Completablefuture Stage variables at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51677094/2711488) and [How to combine 3 or more CompletionStages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34004802/2711488)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
serviceA.thenCompose(a -> serviceB(a).thenCompose(b -> serviceC(a, b)));
```