# How to combine multiple CompletionStage responses of type List(for me) or some other in java

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future, completion-stage

I am trying to create multiple **CompletionStage** of type List, eg. `CompletionStage<List<Car>>`. And at the end I want to merge all the responses of type `<List<Car>>` in to one List in one **CompletionStage**.

```
CompletionStage<List<Car>> completionStageOne= carClientOne.getCarList();
CompletionStage<List<Car>> completionStageTwo= carClientTwo.getCarList();
CompletionStage<List<Car>> completionStageThree= carClientThree.getCarList();
```

So Here, suppose I have 3 different services which will give me different list of car as in response form of `CompletionStage<List<Car>>`

Now I am trying to combine them and creating one common list of cars and here I am getting the problem.
I am using the below code to combine the result

```
CompletionStage<List<Car>> completionStageOneTwo = completionStageOne
.thenCombine(completionStageTwo,(x, y) -> Stream.concat(x.stream(), y.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

//above will work but if I add the third one then it will not. 

CompletionStage<List<Car>> completionStageFinal = completionStageOneTwo
.thenCombine(completionStageThree,(x, y) -> Stream.concat(x.stream(), y.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

and at the end I am doing

```
List<Car> finalList = completionStageFinal.toCompletableFuture().get();
```

So what I am doing wrong? How can I combine this three? Am I blocking something?

Note:  I already checked this [answer from Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005471/545298), but not able to figure out how to use concat there.

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace in your console？

Comment: What do you mean by “_[…] if I add the third one then it will not [work]_”

Comment: @DidierL So When I do, `CompletionStage<List<Car>> completionStageOneTwo = completionStageOne
.thenCombine(completionStageTwo,(x, y) -> Stream.concat(x.stream(), y.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));` It combines two results into one CompletionStage of type List<Car>, But when I try to Combine the **CompletionStageThree** with the **completionStageOneTwo** (which is result of combination of completionStageOne and completionStageTwo ), It don't work.

Comment: It is giving the SocketTimeOutException. `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show you an example. I will show how to use `CompletableFuture.AllOf(...)` which allow waiting for all of the futures.

```
    // create promises to get cars
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> cars1 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Arrays.asList("BMW", "Alfa"));
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> cars2 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.singletonList("WV"));
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> cars3 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.singletonList("FIAT"));

    // collect promises just for convenience
    List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> allFutures = Arrays.asList(cars1, cars2, cars3);

    // wait until all cars will be obtained
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> listCompletableFuture =
            CompletableFuture.allOf(cars1, cars2, cars3)
            .thenApply(avoid -> allFutures  //start to collect them
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(f -> f.join().stream()) //get List from feature. Here these cars has been obtained, therefore non blocking
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );

    // there are here
    listCompletableFuture.join().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
BMW
Alfa
WV
FIAT
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually ran into the same problem and have an example of how I used multiple completable futures to construct an object.

https://github.com/te21wals/CompletableFuturesDemo

It's a little more "enterprisy" than needed, but you should be able to understand the idea.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    CompletableFuture<ClassA> classAfuture = futureProvider.retrieveClassA();
    CompletableFuture<ClassB> classBfuture = futureProvider.retrieveClassB();
    CompletableFuture<ClassC> classCfuture = futureProvider.retrieveClassC();

    System.out.println("starting completable futures ...");
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    ABCData ABCData = CompletableFuture.allOf(classAfuture, classBfuture, classCfuture)
            .thenApply(ignored ->
                    combineFunction.combind(
                            classAfuture.join(),
                            classBfuture.join(),
                            classCfuture.join())
            ).join();

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("completable futures are complete...");
    System.out.println("duration:\t" + Duration.ofNanos(duration).toString());
    System.out.println("result:\t" + ABCData);
}
```

A nice added benefit you get is the total request only takes the time of the longest individual request.