# Play Framework - How to build a web page with multiple MySQL queries

Tags: java, playframework

I've created my first Play Framework Website with Java using the official documentation. It has a single page where I display a list of items that can be filtered or modified.

I have a Controller class with a method:

```
   public CompletionStage<Result> feedpostslist(String domain, String date, String state, int page, int resnum, String search) {
        return feedRepository.getArticleList(domain, date, state, page, resnum, search).thenApplyAsync(articles -> {
            FeedArticle[] list = new FeedArticle[articles.size()];
            articles.toArray(list);
            return ok(views.html.feedpostslist.render(list));
        }, ec.current());
    }
```

This method does a query to the DB (through feedRepository) and then display the result using the view feedpostslist.

Everything is fine but now I need to get other data from the DB to be used in the same web page (so multiple queries). How do I do this in Play Framework? I don't understand what is the best way to do that.

Should I do multiple DB request inside the method showed before (through feedRepository) and then pass all these informations to my view? I don't want to do a mess or even something too heavy to handle.

Comment: What documentation about Play have you read? What tutorials have you accomplished? What exactly is not clear there? Please be more specific. Otherwise your question can be closed as too broad.

Comment: Documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaHome. Tutorials the JPA one: https://github.com/playframework/play-java-jpa-example. I don't find in the documentation any suggestion about how to build a page with multiple data (obtained with multiple queries) from a DB so I need specific advice on how to achieve it in a proper way.

Answer (score 2):

If the second query doesn't depend on the first one you can run them in parallel using combineAsync. This is a good example on how to do that:

https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/2.8.x/play-java-ebean-example/app/controllers/HomeController.java#L85

If the second query depends on results on the first then there's nothing you can do but to wait for the first one to complete and run the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to be ok with 2 queries but what about building a page with 6/7 queries from DB? Is this a good solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004802/how-to-combine-3-or-more-completionstages ?

Comment: What does it even mean to build a page? If your controller method requires 6/7 queries then there is something wrong with your DB schema or app logic.

Comment: My page has a header, a main content, a sidebar and a footer. Each part displays different type of information that has to be retrieved from the DB. You can't manage everything with just 1/2 query

Comment: Maybe you can use ajax to load them in javascript and keep the controller methods simple? Either way seems like your design is also doing a little too much at once.

Comment: If I can't develop a website with Play Framework without heavy relying on AJAX it sounds to me like a very limited framework