# Using CompletableFuture for calculating student percentage

Tags: java, postgresql, java-8, completable-future

I have a function for calculating the student percentage

```
private Double getStudentPercentage() {
   double mathsMark = getMarkForMaths();
   double physicsMark = getMarkForMaths();
   double chemistryMark = getMarkForChemistry();
   double totalPercentage = (mathsMark + physicsMark + chemistryMark) / 3;
   return totalPercentage
}
```

Each of those functions such as `getMarkForMaths()`, `getMarkForMaths()`, `getMarkForChemistry()` does a database interaction (postgres). I know `CompletableFuture` is an non-blocking Asynchronous call by running a task on a separate thread than the main application thread and notifying the main thread about its progress, completion or failure

but like to know if I convert the above call using `CompletableFuture` like as shown below, will it give me any advantages or benefits

```
private Double getStudentPercentage() {
      return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Student::getMarkForMaths())
             .thenApply(total -> total + getMarkForPhysics())
             .thenApply(total -> total + getMarkForChemistry())
             .thenApply(total -> total / 3)
             .get();
}
```

Comment: `thenApply` creates a *dependent* stage whose function will only get evaluated when the prerequisite stage has been completed. There is no benefit in creating a linear chain of dependent stages here. If you want parallelism, you have to create *independent* stages, e.g. `CompletableFuture<Double> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Student::getMarkForMaths), b = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Student::getMarkForPhysics), c = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Student::getMarkForChemistry);`. Then, look at [How to combine 3 or more CompletionStages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34004802/2711488)

Comment: `double result = a.thenCombine(b, Double::sum).thenCombine(c, Double::sum).join() / 3;` but when you are waiting for the final result anyway, `double result = (a.join() + b.join() + c.join()) / 3;` would do as well.