# How to combine a dynamic amount of CompletionStage

Tags: java

How would I combine a dynamic amount of CompletionStage? In my code, I am creating a new CompletionStage (`from personService.shout()`) for every Person and saving the CompletionStage in a list. I am wondering how I would combine all these CompletionStages into a single CompletionStage?

```
List<CompletionStage<PersonReply>> replies = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person person: people) {
    replies.add(personService.shout(person.getId()));
}
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005471/1054937) SO response, but the solutions involve a non dynamic amount of CompletionStages.

Comment: if you just want wait all CompletionStage finished and then do something,method from@aran is good，but if you want get the combined result thenCombine method may helpful.